# Variables in a loaded view

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I load a view like this:

```
$this->load->view ('lineups/printable-lineups.php', $data);
```

in a current view can I access somehow to the variables of the `printable-lineups.php`?

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html#adding-logic-to-the-controller: here you read in the manual how to access $data inside the view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access variables in view, here is example, basic is you can pass either an array or an object to the view from controller, you can then access the array key(s) as a variable(s) in your view.

> You may refer more about views from [Codeigniter » Docs » General
>   Topics » Views](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

```
<?php

 /* Your controller in application/controllers directory */
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Home extends CI_Controller
 {

    public function index()
    {  
      /* pass whatever you want to access in view */
      $data = array('foo'=>123, 'bar'=>456); 
      $this->load->view ('lineups/printable-lineups.php', $data);
    }
 }
```

In your view/template `lineups/printable-lineups.php`, usually in `application/views` directory, then you can access them like below

```
 foo :<?php echo $foo;?>
 bar :<?php echo $bar;?>
```

Comment: what I was trying to say is, if a create a variable in the loaded view, can i access to it out of it view?, the view is loaded inside another view